# I update state inside useEffect and expect webpage to rerender on every state update

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I update state inside useEffect and expect webpage to rerender on every state update but it seems like it only updates once - the last value from for loop. And despite me setting timeout the update and rerender happens instantly. What am I doing wrong?

```
const [definition, setDefinition] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
        if (startAnimationFinished) return
        if (!pathIsActive) return

        let newDef
        for (let i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
            newDef = `M ${i} ${i} L ${i} ${i}`
            setTimeout(() => {
                setDefinition(newDef)
            }, 1000)
        }

        console.log(newDef);

        startAnimationFinished = true
    }, [pathIsActive])

    return (
        <>
            <svg
                className={'path' + (pathIsActive ? ' active' : '')}
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                style={{ border: '1px solid blue' }}
                viewBox={`${-width / 4} ${-width / 4} ${width} ${width}`}
                {...props}
            >
                <path fill='none' stroke="white" width='1'
                    style={{ filter: "drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px white)" }}
                    d={definition}
                />
            </svg>
        </>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. React state updates are [batched](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), meaning multiple subsequent updates can trigger only one re-render
2. You are effectively scheduling all `setTimeout`s to run at the same time
3. Because of the inherent behaviour of closures, all the `setTimeout`s will see the same value of the `newDef` variable (which will be the last assigned value).

If you want to update the state in 1 second intervals you can do something like this:

```
const updateEverySecond = async () => {
  let i = 0;

  while (i++ < 150) {
     const newDef = `M ${i} ${i} L ${i} ${i}`;

     setDefinition(newDef);

     await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  updateEverySecond();
}, []);
```

Comment: Ok. Could you recommend the correct way to do what im trying to do?

Comment: @PRRS26-8-6turbineengine I edited my response with the added example.

Comment: @AntonPodolsky Don't block the loop, let it run . You can modify the code like 
```
while (i++ < 150) {
      const newDef = `M ${i} ${i} L ${i} ${i}`;

      setTimeout(() => {
        setDefinition(newDef);
      }, 1000);
    }
```
It will run the same. If you want delay in UI use ```setInterval``` not with loop

Comment: @MallikarjunMG 

1. The loop is not blocked, as in "doesn't block execution of other code"
2. Using setInterval doesn't really simplify the solution because you need to clear it eventually.
3. setInterval is usually not recommended https://dev.to/akanksha_9560/why-not-to-use-setinterval--2na9

Comment: Yes code will work, OP wants to animate the UI per sec.

Answer (score 1):

> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance. Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

consider updating multiple `hooks` in your `useEffect`, this will not be good behavior if the `component` will be rendered for every update. so once `useEffect` ends the `component` re render.

here if you want to store all the values without loosing any, because here you are overwritting the value of `definition` in every itteration you can declare `definition` as `array`

```
const [definition, setDefinition] = useState([]);
```

then update it like this :

```
let newDef = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
  newDef.push(`M ${i} ${i} L ${i} ${i}`)
}
setDefinition(newDef)
```

now you have the list of definitions you can display them as you want

Answer (score 1):

If you want start animation per sec use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeOut`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [definition, setDefinition] = React.useState("");
  const [secs, setSecs] = useState(0);
  const [pathIsActive, setActivePath] = useState(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let timerId;
    let startAnimationFinished = false;
    const startAnim = () => {
      if (!startAnimationFinished && !pathIsActive) {
        let newDef;
        timerId = setInterval(() => {
          newDef = `M ${secs} ${secs} L ${secs} ${secs}`;
          setDefinition(newDef);
          setSecs((pre) => pre + 1);
        }, 1000);
      }
    };
    const stopAnim = () => {
      clearInterval(timerId);
      startAnimationFinished = true;
    };
    if (secs <= 150) {
      startAnim();
    } else {
      stopAnim();
    }
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timerId);
      startAnimationFinished = false;
    };
  }, [secs, pathIsActive]);
  return (
    <>
      <svg
        className={"path" + (pathIsActive ? " active" : "")}
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        style={{ border: "1px solid blue" }}
        viewBox={`${-width / 4} ${-width / 4} ${width} ${width}`}
        {...props}
      >
        <path
          fill="none"
          stroke="white"
          width="1"
          style={{ filter: "drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px white)" }}
          d={definition}
        />
      </svg>
    </>
  );
}
```